Unity-related Refreshing Algorithm
Good day everyone. I'm currently developing a video game in the Unity Game Engine, and recently I have discovered that my project suffers a serious issue with performance, specifically for transferring items between inventory slots, and I can't figure out a solution to fix it. Here is the algorithm:
private void Redraw() // ORIGINAL Redraw Function
        {
            foreach (Transform child in transform)
            {
                Destroy(child.gameObject);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedInventory.GetSize(); i++)
            {
                var itemUI = Instantiate(InventoryItemPrefab, transform);
                itemUI.Setup(selectedInventory, i);
            }
        }

As you can see, this algorithm is simple, and all it does is destroy every single inventory slot, re-instantiates them and then sets up each slot accordingly
Now because my game has a banking system, with a total of 323 slots (inventory + bank), this operation can be pretty expensive, and it drastically slows down the game the longer I use it
Is there any alternative solution to develop a cleaner method to improve this performance issue? My goal is to only refresh the UI of the slots that actually undergo a change, and delete any garbage data from Unity when this operation is done, so the space can be free for the next one
I tried implementing a dictionary that holds additional information, but as I am not the best with memory (i.e: I forget stuff so easily, literally), I failed to understand what I was even doing, so I scrapped my own attempts out...

https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling

I recall someone who had the same algorithm as me say that object pooling did not perform an excellent job... I think they did end up making a dictionary and it worked for them.
And for a variety of items in the game, especially if they're going to be a lot, is pooling really the best approach to the problem?

why do you ever need to destroy them? the slot should just need updating with the item it holds,

I promise you if I knew a way to do this, I would have done it... I'm trying my best with whatever I know. For now, the last thing my tutor did (I'm following a course for that tbh) was just destroy all children inventory slots and update them all over again... Which baffles me, but if I knew a way to update each slot individually, I would.
Not arguing with you here, just doing my best

Pooling helps with avoiding creating a lot of garbage when recycling items and creating a lot of garbage can lead to inconsistent performance when the GC kicks in. I agree with @BugFinder though, seems like you should just be able to call itemUI.Setup(selectedInventory, i); on an existing item to reconfigure it.

well @BahaaSoliman I bet you know a for loop? as you used one, so, you if absolutely nothing else can start at the bottom and run setup on each one, so it picks up new settings, or depending on what setup does, maybe trim back that, because you make them at one point and reuse again...
